# Speeding up Julia on terminal for the second run

Tags: julia

Running a Julia file in REPL

```
julia> include("foo.jl")
julia> include("foo.jl")
```

gives different running time but it doesn't seem to be the case when I run it from the terminal

```
$ julia foo.jl
$ julia foo.jl
```

Is there a standard method for saving compiled files outside of Julia?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50608970/4183191

Comment: Hmm, the answer seems to indicate that running from the command line is always a bad idea. I am using MPI.jl and they seem to require to use the command line...

Comment: not at all. read my answer in that page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally Julia compiles functions the first time they're used within a given Julia instance, so each time you call `julia foo.jl` from the command line it will need to re-compile whatever code is called in `foo.jl`.

If you want to store a compiled version of `foo.jl`, you can use the `PackageCompiler` package (https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl) which will replace your original Julia binary (where the code in `foo.jl` has not been compiled) with a new one where `foo.jl` has been compiled.

Note that you probably don't want to do this if you're actively developing `foo.jl` as it takes some time to make each new Julia sysimage. If that's the case, you can just create a small script that loads all the packages and calls the same functions you want to call. Once that sysimage is compiled you should be able to import the same packages and use the same functions with no additional compilation time.

Answer (score 2):

If you're re-running it to test changes to the underlying code, also consider using [Revise](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl).

Answer (score 0):

There is a Julia package for running Julia as a daemon: https://github.com/dmolina/DaemonMode.jl which is worth checking out. Doesn't exactly answer the question about "how to save compiled Julia code" but it could probably improve the workflow you are after.